# Can mexican salamander regenerate any organ?

Tags: cell-biology, regeneration

Mexican salamander or few other species of salamander can regenerate limbs, tail etc. Do they have *HOX* genes for vital organs like liver, heart, brain, kidney?

If brain is damaged, can salamander grow it's brain to normal functioning again ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you meant *Ambystoma mexicanum* also known as the axolotl. There are other kinds of salamanders that live in Mexico, but the axolotl is widely-studied and sometimes called the 'mexican salamander'.

The axolotl has exceptional regenerative powers, and although I suspect this ability is shared among salamander larvae(even if not the adults) there's not much research into phylogenetic distribution of regenerative capability. So in the absence of a more refined answer I'm going to hope axolotl results generalize to other salamanders.

Axolotls, as long as they don't die, can regenerate [nearly any](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23327114) part of their brain. As a rule, as long as they don't die they can regenerate from any injury. There are a couple exceptions(it's very hard to keep an axolotl alive without a heart, so that hasn't been tested) like [the eye](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1741-7007/10/103) but in general they can grow back nearly anything.

The [Hox gene research](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1741-7007/10/103) I've found was done explicitly on worms and frogs, but I would feel safe concluding that axolotl regeneration relied on a similar mechanism, and that therefore they have Hox genes for internal organs. I mean, they had to grow them the first time, right?

Comment: So until he not get  killed he is immortal ?

Comment: They still die of old age, unfortunately.

Comment: They have regeneration power so they can replace old tissues ? Its stranger they become old :|

Comment: They're still subject to cellular aging as far as I know. As they age their regenerative abilities fade, until eventually they die. Similar to humans, really, but our regenerative abilities are *much* reduced.